# .NET Core : NUnit won't execute SetUp

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

NUnit won't execute the SetUp method unless i call it manually. Additionally when i add SetUp() to my test it seems i also have an issue with the test server because i get "StatusCode: 204, ReasonPhrase: 'No Content'" in the response, but the controller works fine if i execute it. I'm using .NET Core 1.1 and NUnit 3.6.1.

Solution is here https://github.com/Narcil/NUnitMCV

My test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FrontendControllerTests : AbstractFrontendTestFixtures
{
    [Test]
    public async Task FrontendAppSettingsTest()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/values");
        var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsTrue(value.Equals("Some FrontendValue"));
    }

}
```

My abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractFrontendTestFixtures
{
    protected HttpClient _client;
    protected TestServer _server;

    [SetUp]
    protected void SetUp()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Frontend.Startup>()
            .UseEnvironment("Testing"));
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [TearDown]
    protected void TearDown()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `[Setup]`/`[Teardown]` need to be on public methods,

Comment: Thanks. The response is still always noContent .

Answer (score 1):

Your `SetUp` method should be `public`. If you would like to have additional setup logic in derived classes, just mark the method as `virtual` in additional.